# How to create an image as small as a cloud image?

Tags: server, btrfs, disk-image

Creating an Ubuntu 22.04 server image with the official .iso and VirtualBox, for it to be on BTRFS subvolumes, I ended up with more than 4GB of virtual disk.

How do I create an image that is as nice and lean as the .img file here: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/jammy/current/ ?

Thank you in advance for any pointers.
The solution should be well documented and preferrably with a tutorial to make it more human. :)

Comment: When I compared a Jammy install from ISO (using the "Ubuntu Server" image) to the pre-built Jammy cloud image I found they were nearly identical.  Can you be more specific about what you consider nice and lean?  One obvious option could be to install the "Ubuntu Server (minimized)" image.

Comment: Thanks for you insights Andrew! The nice and lean image is around 600MB. A lot smaller than my 4GB. Maybe you know of common mistakes when building an image? Also I was thinking of something like image-building like for Core, but for "normal" server installs.
P.S.: Also trying to -compact the image file with VirtualBox did not have an effect.